# Can the official tutorial 'View-your-model' provided by Autodesk Forge be deploy on a real web server, instead of localhost:3000?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have followed the "View Your Models" tutorial provided by Autodesk Forge, and the codes are running perfectly under both the IIS Express 10.0 and Tomcat 9.0 locally. I'm wondering if I can publish the same codes on a real machine, instead of like 'localhost:3000'.

I've tried to deploy the codes onto either IIS or Tomcat with an domain name/IP and a port, but it showed me all kinds of errors, such as:

Internal Server Error when deploying to IIS
"iisnode encountered an error when processing the request"

Or

"net::ERR_ABORTED 404" accessing those client-side files (ForgeViewer.js or TorgeTree.js, etc)
 when deploying to Tomcat with a different port

It seems to me that the tutorial has to be run on virtual machine, with an URL like 'http://localhost:3000'. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not related to the Forge platform directly, I would advise you to check these documentations from their vendors or other supports. For example,

- [Configuring the Tomcat Server](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fconfiguration.html)
- [HOW TO CONFIGURE IIS TO ACCESS WEBSITE USING IP ADDRESS?](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html), and change the IP address to * to listen to all IPs of your server.

Comment: The links you provided are irrelevant to his questions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not true - there's no fundamental difference between your "virtual server" (or IIS Express/Tomcat on your local terminal) and a "real machine"(or full IIS/Tomcat on a virtualized/bare metal server) ...

To answer your specific questions:

> "net::ERR_ABORTED 404" accessing those client-side files (ForgeViewer.js or TorgeTree.js, etc) when deploying to Tomcat with a different port

When running apps on a detached Tomcat server you will need to explicitly specify servlet mapping to serve static files in your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

> Internal Server Error when deploying to IIS "iisnode encountered an error when processing the request"

This is too general to narrow the issue down - can you post the error log (browser output and see them persisted [here](https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2487/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx)) in your question and leave a comment when you are done so I will fill out my answer here?